# Woocommerce redirect after checkout based on product custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So i have custom text field meta in the product so that if has a url i would like to redirect users to a custom TY page after checkout. Here is my code and not redirecting!!

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_redirect_after_purchase');
function my_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $post, $wp;

    $my_redirect = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_redirect', true ); // This has the redirect URL entered in the field tested and working
    if ( '' !== $my_redirect ) { // am checking here if the field is not empty

        if (!empty($wp->query_vars['order-received'])) {

                    wp_redirect(esc_url($my_redirect)); 
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried few other ways but no luck too. Am guessing the query for order-recieved runs after and thus the meta returns empty?

How should i go about this? Thanks

Comment: When you are on the checkout page `get_the_ID()` will return that page id, not product id( that's you are expecting ) that's why this will not work. and how you will decide which link to redirect if you have many products in the cart?

Comment: I am actually checking out directly from product page use woocommerce one page checkout. Also lets say we are doing this from the checkout page, how to go about this? Can you help me with a code snippet? Example loop if the cart items has item with custom meta and thus make the conditional redirect work

Comment: loop if the cart item has an item with a custom meta and thus make the conditional redirect work => Yes this will work you have to iterate the loop of cart items. but how do you decide if there are many products in the cart?

Comment: I am only allowing one product per checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to get order items using `wc_get_order` then you can get meta based on product id. Try the below code.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_redirect_after_purchase');
function my_redirect_after_purchase() {

    /* return if we are not on order-received page */
    if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) || empty( $_GET['key'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] );
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $my_redirect = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'] , '_my_redirect', true );
        if( $my_redirect != '' ){
            wp_redirect( $my_redirect );
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I put a very similar code that loops around the the cart item `foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) `  but yours by far better and works :)